# AppleScript Get HTML of Chrome Active Tab

Tags: applescript, google-chrome, html

Is there a way to get the actual `HTML` of a current active tab in `Chrome`?  Some websites use the position on the page to induce an `AJAX` call to expand the page further.  So working with a `URL` only won't cut it.  Actually grabbing the current `HTML` is what I'm after.

At the moment, I can ask `Chrome` to open a new tab with the source of the tab, but that's a bit cumbersome.  The libraries haven't shown me anything with regards to grabbing current active `HTML`.

Can I somehow use `AppleScript` to get the current active tab `HTML`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to grab the **HTML** of the active tab of the front window of **Google Chrome** using **AppleScript**:

```
tell application "Google Chrome" to set sourceHTML to ¬
    execute front window's active tab javascript "document.documentElement.outerHTML"
```

---

Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and does not contain any error handling as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any error handling as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1).

Comment: Looks like you got a winner.  Mine was similar, again, with making a new tab.  This one is cleaner.  Excellent